# Automatically sending mails to Content Authors if the content's modification date exceeds 2 years in WCM

Tags: websphere-portal, wcm

I have a requirement in IBM WCM which can Automatically send mails to Content Authors if the content's modification date exceeds 2 years. What should be the best approach to achieve this?
Please let me know the steps and links which can guide me in achieving this. I am using WCM 7.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is understand what is WCM workflows, stages and actions.

- Actions are atomic functions that applied to your content items (publish, expire, email)
- Stages are sets of actions to get complete impact on content items (publish item, call custom code, notify users)
- Workflows are set of stages. For example WCM has default three steps    workflow - Draft, Publish, Expire.

Go to Applications -> Web Content -> Library -> Workflow items

You need workflow with two stages:

- Publish
- Expire

Your publish stage must contain two actions:

- Publish action
- Scheduled move action (Live date + offset = 24 month) This action will move your content to next stage

You Expire stage must content two actions:

- Expire
- Email action to send nitifications

More details [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Web%20Content%20Manager%207%20Product%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Creating_items_wcm7&content=pdcontent)

Comment: Thanks Georgy for the help.

Comment: Hi Georgy, I have one doubt here...I want the mail notification if the content has not been modified for 2 years. I think this cannot be achieved by using Scheduled Move action. Can you please tell me what can be done if I want the email notification at the time when the content has crossed 2 years without any modification ?

Comment: Hey. Take a look on WCM API, you can check modified content between two dates workspace.findContentModifiedBetween(d1, d2), for example today and two years back, then you can move this content to next stage through WCM API - content.nextWorkflowStage